# PySimpleGUI code to run specific RunCell in the code?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

that is my first question here so if I missed any rule let me know. I am also very beginner in coding so my approach might not be efficient in some cases.

I wrote a Python code (using Visual Studio Code) to automate one of my main work process. The whole code I divided with #%% on parts. So I run each cell one by one, because after each cell I do manual quality checks. So the code looks like:

```
#%%
code part 1
#base on output i do checks and decision if I can move forward with code

#%%
code part 2
#base on output i do checks and decision if I can move forward with code

#%%
code part ...

#%%
code part 9

end
```

Now, I would like to add GUI with which I will control which part of the code should be run and output of that portion will be presented to me within the output window.

I`m missing knowledge how to refer button in my GUI code to run specific RunCell in the code?

I`m using PySimpleGUI and so far code looks like:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg      

layout = [[sg.Text('Persistent window')],      
          [sg.InputText(key='_OUTPUT_')],      
          [sg.Button('RunCell_1'), sg.Exit()],
          [sg.Button('RunCell_2')]]      

window = sg.Window('Window that stays open', layout)      

while True:
    event, values = window.read() 
    print(event, values)       
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    if event == 'RunCell_1' #what now, how specify which part to run?
        if out: window['_OUTPUT_'].update(values['values from main code'])

window.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if event == 'RunCell_1` should end with `:`
as to your question. It would depend on how the rest of your code is set up. if you have each "code part" as a function that you want to run. you could do something like this

```
def cell_1():
    print('do cell_1 stuff here')
def cell_2():
    print('do cell_2 stuff here')
def gui():
    layout = [[sg.Text('Persistent window')],
              [sg.InputText(key='_OUTPUT_')],
              [sg.Button('RunCell_1'), sg.Exit()],
              [sg.Button('RunCell_2')]]

    window = sg.Window('Window that stays open', layout)

    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        print(event, values)
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
            break
        if event == 'RunCell_1':#what now, how specify which part to run?
            cell_1()
        if event == 'RunCell_2':
            cell_2()
            #if out: window['_OUTPUT_'].update(values['values from main code'])

    window.close()
gui()
```

also highly recommend checking out the [Pysimplgui cookbook](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook/) if you haven't already. as well as the [call references](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/call%20reference/). When things start getting more complex this can help answer a lot of questions

Comment: Thanks, I just learnt how to work with functions and move dataframes between them other than work with whole set of code :)